# Working with objectives and calling methods?

Tags: c++

I've probably become a bit to used to Java and am finding this harder than it should be. Heres what I have.

```
myObject[0] = new item1(this);

class item1
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;

public:    
    item1( passedPointer* pOne )
    {
        x = 5;
        y = 5;
    }

    int returnX() { return x; }

    int returnY() { return y; }
}
```

Then in another method I thought I could just say:

```
void check()
{
    int y = item1.returnY();
    int x = item1.returnX();            
}
```

But I am getting the common error: a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.

There is only one instance of this class item1, what would be the best way to do this? This is just a simplified fragment of what I'm actually doing, not the actual code.

Comment: You should skim a book on OOP in C++. It differs a bit from Java.

Comment: You should post the actual code, as the code you posted makes no sense in neither C++ nor Java.

Comment: would this code work in java? Can you assign a function to an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item1 is a class.  You have to create an instance of it before you can access its non-static members.  Try looking [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) for some basic information.

Answer (score 3):

```
void check(){
   int y = item1.returnY;
   int x = item1.returnX;  
}
```

This would also be incorrect in Java, since neither `returnX` nor `returnY` are statics, you need an object on which to apply the operation, and you also need the parenthesis of the method call:

```
void check() {
   item1 i;
   int y = i.returnY();
   int x = i.returnX();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps implementing the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) would not do you harm, since you want only one instance of the object. You could declare the object as global or static to a function too, then get the values.

Then again, you could also declare the functions as static, and add another one to initialize the static values of the variables which need to be returned by those methods. There are a lot of solutions to this depending on your situation which can not be fully grasped by the short amount of code you have pasted.

Answer (score 2):

You created an instance of class item1 with the line

```
myObject[0] = new item1(this);
```

Unlike JAVA, in C++ there are pointers and new returns a pointer to the object (so myObject[0] is a pointer to the instance) so you need the -> operator. To activate the method you should write:

```
myObject[0]->returnX();
```

If you wish to have only one instance than implement the class as a singleton.